# Sum fields according a condition

Tags: jasper-reports

I have two fields in my report.

Value of the bill without tax `$F{valorTotal}` and and other with tax `$F{valorJuros}`.

Well, I'd like to sum the field  `$F{valorTotal}` when field `$F{valorJuros}` is equal `0.0`, but when `$F{valorJuros}` is greater then 0.0 this field must be used.

I tried something like this:
`$F{valorJuros} > 0.0 ? $V{total} + $F{valorJuros} : $V{total} + $F{valorTotal}`
where `$V{total}` is the field that have the total sum.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: what error do you get? or what is the output of that? it seems correct programatically but will get more idea if you share your problem.

Answer (score 0):

What I can guess from your question and variables is that you are using $V{total} variable not field at the end that has total for some category, as total is added at the end of the category and your values for ${valorTotal} and ${valorJuros} are added just from the query so that can be the possible reason. Try to remove $V{total} and see if values are correct if YES you have to define $V{total} somewhere there it is also updated with those fields or take it from DB as a field and then add.